# stop phonecall before voicemail

Tags: android

Is it possible in Android to make a service that stops the phone-call when the voice-mail is almost reached so that the user is not billed for the connection cost on the mobile network?

I was looking to let the service recognize the voice-mail but how can i let the app know the difference between a normal call and a voice-mail call?

Thanks for your answer(s)

Comment: what? like, guessing that no one will answer and therefore you'll end on their voicemail, and hanging up before that?

Comment: and you plan to do that using the psychic powers of the phone ?

Comment: If that is possible. I was thinking of using a timer to know the time it takes to reach the voicemail. Then it should reach the voice mail one time. After hanging up the service should ask the user if it was the voice mail. If it was that, then it should remember the time and end the call the next time before entering the voice mail.

Comment: can't do. depends on each person you'll call. can be 2,4, 6, or any number of tones before going to voicemail. plus, can be direct to voicemail, if the phone is off, and can be at any time if the person hangs up immediatly

Comment: ok, i didn't think about that. What you say is important because it is happening a lot that users put their phone off or end the call early.

Comment: If the phone is off or the person hangs up early the app can also fire up an alert dialog with the question: "Was that the voice-mail?" and with a yes or no button. Then the user should push the no button.

Comment: how will it help to know if it was the voice mail who answered ?

Comment: That should the user do by pressing yes or no. If it is yes than the app should save the ringing time and the next time it should hang up automatically just before the voice mail is reached. But the the next problem is how i let the app know that he calls for the second time.

Comment: anyway, in a regular app, you cannot simply hang up automatically